# Can't export string variables

Tags: bash, variable

I am trying to export some string variables from txt file.

file.txt

> ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_ARCH_MSG='ERROR: Unknown arch'
>   ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_OS_V_MSG='ERROR: Not supported os version'

```
$ source file.txt
$ export $(cut -f 1 file.txt)
```

and I am getting error like -

> export: `arch'': not a valid identifier

So the question is if it is possible to export string variable with white spaces? What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with :

```
cut -d= -f1
```

compare :

```
CD > cut -d= -f1 file1.txt 
ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_ARCH_MSG
ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_OS_V_MSG
CD > cut  -f1 file1.txt 
ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_ARCH_MSG='ERROR: Unknown arch' 
ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_OS_V_MSG='ERROR: Not supported os version'
```

- `-d=` use `=` as delimiter

Comment: @Rokas.ma It would be pollite since answer solves your problem to accept the answer.